# How to avoid multiple instances on Parse.com?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

This is code from Parse docs. Each time I run it, I have another object created. I just want to create it once, next only update (I.E. position etc, not counter of a game score)

You from Parse, I think it's a simple but common issue, how can I fix it? I suppose I should retrieve the objectId after the first entry, then make a query, but how ?

edit after Wain comment

```
//MARK: example from parse
    //*******************************************************

    //single PFObject countains: score: 1337, playerName: "Sean Plott", cheatMode: false

    //let's make object

    let kUserDefaultsParseId = "UserDefaultsParseId"
    let KIdGotFromParse: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(kUserDefaultsParseId)


    if KIdGotFromParse == nil {

//let firstEntry = "bi4riOeqdA"

    var gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
    gameScore["score"] = 1337
    gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott"
    gameScore["cheatMode"] = false
    gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            // The object has been saved.

            var theId = gameScore.objectId

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(theId, forKey: kUserDefaultsParseId)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        } else {
            // There was a problem, check error.description
        }
    }
    } else {


//        //retrive objects
//        var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
//        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(firstEntry) {
//            (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
//            if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
//                println(gameScore)
//            } else {
//                println(error)
//            }
//        }



    var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(theId) {
        (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
            gameScore["cheatMode"] = true
            gameScore["score"] = 30
            gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
        }
    }
    }
    //*******************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you have `the object has been saved` you can get the `id` and save it somewhere, like user defaults. If you have it saved then query for it, otherwise create a new one and save the id.

Comment: Thanks! but now I have an issue herequery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(theId) could you help me out? I have an error even if i use :         let KIdGotFromParse = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(kUserDefaultsParseId) as String

Comment: What's the error? Getting the id from defaults you should then query, if you don't get it you should create

Comment: one error is on the "if KIdGotFromParse == nil" check, regarding nil the error message is: "type String does not conform to protocol NILLIteralConvertible" maybe I don't perform right some query.

Comment: You should use th `let` approach instead of `== nil`

Comment: Please, could you show me what you mean? I'm at my third app and not so expert.

Comment: `if let KIdGotFromParse = KIdGotFromParse { // query } else { // create }`